# Users on my network cant open the Sql server linked tables from their MS Access Form

Tags: sql-server, ms-access

Hi there hopefully this makes sense. 
I have split the database into backend and Frontend.
In the frontend i also have added some linked tables from a SQL Database which are on the network. The DNS files are in the same folder as the front. Now when ive copied across the frontend to the end users desktop when they try to open the table via a form they get the error: "ODBC Call failed" anyone know why that might be?

1 of the end users is using the free version of ms access(2016 runtime) and other has full MS Access but both get the same error.

As it wasnt happening during the development stage on my computer and my collegues. I am a bit lost on how to fix the issue other than convert the linked tables to local tables and do a weekly update of them from the SQL server via my computer where the links work.

Seeing as a normal backend table that is linked to the front works fine. Just would like it to directly call the information from the SQl Server.

Comment: Do these other users have the DSN entry for this server in their ODBC administrator?

Comment: First, a few troubleshooting questions: 1) did you grant permissions for each user in SSRS, to the DB (with read/write for the tables or db_reader + db_writer)? 2) can the users reach & connect to the DB (without your app)?  ODBC is a nice way to test it. 3) Did you design your MS Access database to connect to SQL server via ODBC?  4) if so, did you configure ODBC on each user's worstation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure on your development workstation you link the table using a FILE DSN. When you link, Access then converts the links to what we call DSN-less.

The above means then you don’t have to copy or setup or use ANY kind of DSN on each workstation. So do NOT use a “system” DSN – that uses settings in the registry that you have to setup on each workstation.

The next issue to be aware of is which SQL driver you use to link the tables. If you use the “standard” SQL Driver when linking, then you can be SURE those drivers are installed by default on each workstation.

If you use “Native 11” (or later), then you have to ensure that the Native 11 (or later) drivers are installed on each workstation for this to work. The native drivers are better choice, but they are not by default installed on each workstation.

So I suggest you delete the links, or use the linked table manager to re-link the tables – just make sure you use a FILE dsn – since once the tables are linked, then Access ignores and does not use the DSN anymore – you don’t need it, and you could even delete the DSN and you linked tables will still work.

Comment: Hi there Albert thanks a lot that has solved the issue.

Comment: Just wondering would that mean i couldnt use a pass through query? As they normally run off of System DSN dont they?

Comment: PT query works the same as linked tables. if you use a file dsn, then it becomes DSN less. You not need to set or use a connection string in VBA if you use this approach. The "connection" you use for the linked tables, or a PT query are the same. They both don't require a dsn on the computer as long as you used "file" dsn when setting up the PT query, or the linked table. They both (pt + linked table) become DSN-less by default when created via a FILE dsn.